# Pass params using button_to or button_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im currently working on a ruby on rails app and im having a problem regarding passing parameters using button_to or button_tag

The scenario is i can't pass the parameter using button_tag or when using button_to i can't go to my controller it says "AuthenticityToken"

is there any way or proper way on passing parameter to a controller using button?.

```
        <%= button_tag "Update", :type => 'button', :class => "btn btn-info", :onclick => "location.href = 'student/displayStudent'" , params: {id: student.student_name}%>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= button_tag "Update", :name => 'id', :value => student.student_name, :type => 'button', :class => "btn btn-info", :onclick => "location.href = 'student/displayStudent'" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
<%= button_to 'Update', {:controller => "students", :action => "displayStudent", :id => student.student_name}, :method=>:put %>
```

Comment: authenticitytoken appended in the url. it did not go to my controller

Comment: @Nikita Singh: controller's name always in `plural` , you need to change `student` to `students` and `update` methods are `PUT` request type. change it before start getting downvotes from others

Answer (score 0):

My bad, i declared a form then used the button_to with a action and controller that's why it display authenticity token

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
<%= button_to "Update", 'student/displayStudent', params: {id: student.student_name}, method: :put  %>
```

Answer (score -3):

do this in your controller (top)

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

If you don't want to use this you can pass the data via Javascript like this,

```
$(".div").bind('click', function(){

$.ajax({
  url: '/controller/'+this.value+'/action',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {"data": value}
});


});
```